# In symfony2 with sonata: How to pass a variable to the template defined for a given field of the listmapper in the method configureListFields?

Tags: symfony-sonata, sonata-admin, listfield

Using Symfony2 with Sonata, in a list, fields templates can be overwritten and assigning  variables to templates, i.e setTemplateVar(), can sometimes be useful! (not talking about form where 'attr' serves this purpose but list...)

I would like to know what would be the best approach to pass a variable to the template defined for a given field of the listmapper in the method configureListFields ?

```
    <?php

    namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Admin;

    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

    class AcmeAdmin extends Admin
    {

        protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
        {
            $listMapper
                ->addIdentifier('acme_field')
                ->add('date', 'date', array(
                    'template'   => "AcmeBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig",
            //        'dateFormat' => "Y-m-d",// ---> how to pass this var to twig ?
                ))
                ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                    'actions' => array(
                        'edit'   => array(),
                        'delete' => array(),
                    ),
                ))
            ;
        }
```

A solution to the specific problem of translating and formatting the date is already implemented with the twig template as follows:

```
    {% block field%}
        {% if value is empty %}
            &nbsp;
        {% else %}

            {# retrieving the dateFormat variable from the listmapper #}
            {% if dateFormat is defined %}
                {{ value|date(dateFormat)|title }}
            {% else %}
                {{ value|date('m / Y') }}
            {% endif %}

            {# passing the locale in some way here would be great, it is not available in twig.. #}
            {# scratch that, it is not necessary with intl.extension... #}
            {% if locale is defined %}
                {% set dflt_locale = locale %}
            {% else %}
                {% set dflt_locale = 'fr_FR.UTF-8' %}
            {% endif %}

            {{ value|localizeddate('medium', 'none', dflt_locale)|title }}

        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
```

However, my goal is to be able to retrieve a variable there from the listmapper.
In the example proposed, the dateFormat would be a good one to pass along...

*The issue about the locale is fine actually, as I realized it does not need to be passed to localizeddate... it is already available through the intl extension.*

The following post answer lead me to that conclusion as I could not define locale, but by not adding the parameter it was resolved!
[Localize dates in twigs using Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480325/localize-dates-in-twigs-using-symfony-2)
hence:

```
    {{ value|localizeddate('medium', 'none')|title }}
```

Cheers in advance for any response related to the dateFormat parameter!

Vinz

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try in the Twig

```
field_description.options.YOURFIELDNAME
```

defined here

```
->add('date', 'date', array(
                    'template'   => "AcmeBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig",
                    'YOURFIELDNAME' => 'Blablo'
                ))
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the most straightforward solution was to define a var in the Admin class as follows:

```
        <?php

        namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Admin;

        use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
        use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
        use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
        use Sonata\AdminBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;
        use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;

        class AcmeAdmin extends Admin
        {
            // two options to define var and make them available to twig by admin. mechanism
            public $dateFormat = "Y-m-d";// ---> this var is available in twig : admin.dateFormat
            // or to allow better relation to context
            public $parameters = array();// ---> this array is available in twig : admin.parameters.x.y.z

            protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
            {
                // assuming the $dateFormat is not set, by convention it could be defined here with proper intent in mind
                // it could then be contained in an array like that

                $this->parameters = array('listmapper' => array('dateFormat' => 'Y-m-d',),);

                // then specialized in twig : admin.parameters.listmapper.dateFormat

                $listMapper
                    ->addIdentifier('acme_field')
                    ->add('date', 'date', array(
                        'template'   => "AcmeBundle:CRUD:list_date.html.twig",// checking admin.parameters.listmapper.dateFormat
                    ))
                    ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
                        'actions' => array(
                            'edit'   => array(),
                            'delete' => array(),
                        ),
                    ))
                ;
            }
```

Then in twig:

```
            {% block field%}
            {% if value is empty %}
                &nbsp;
            {% else %}

                {# retrieving the dateFormat variable from the listmapper by convention...
                    twig is very forgiving in eval, so checking for defined var is peachy
                    e.g if admin.parameters is not defined or empty then else is triggered
                #}
                {% if admin.parameters.listmapper.dateFormat is defined %}

                    {{ value|date(admin.parameters.listmapper.dateFormat)|title }}

                {% else %}

                    {{ value|localizeddate('medium', 'none')|title }}

                {% endif %}

            {% endif %}
            {% endblock %}
```

Thanks to [Sonata Admin: Add custom triggers/actions to list/edit action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482910/sonata-admin-add-custom-triggers-actions-to-list-edit-action?rq=1) I realized/remembered/connected the dots... that twig has access to the admin variable, so by defining a variable in the class we can retrieve it in twig.

Now, it is just a question of convention to put in place a sort of constraint to a container for the admin variables. (cf parameters array)

For this particular case, this solution does not add any point as localizeddate serves well my purpose, however, for the sake of the argument it is good to know IMHO.

Cheers,
Hope that helps!

Vinz